# PHP foreach not returning the string i need

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

i got this little problem with an array. I have products that belong to one or more categories and i need to display them as an array. First, this is my code to get categories from product 1 only:

```
    $prod = $this->getDi()->productTable->load(1);
    $prod_cat = $prod->getCategories();
    print_r($prod_cat);
```

This will output this:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 )
```

So far so good. However, i need to do the same for all the products in existence at once. So im doing this:

```
$act_prod = Array ( 0 => 1 ); //array can contain more than one product, as of now it only contains one

foreach ($act_prod as $act) {
         $cat = $this->getDi()->productTable->load($act);
         $active_cat[$act] = $cat->getCategories(); 
        } 
print_r($active_cat);
```

But this will output:

```
Array ( [1] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) )
```

which is not what i need but this instead:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 )
```

I cant figure out whats wrong. Could you please give me a hint?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm quite confused. What is your expected output in the loop?

Comment: I expect this: Array ( [0] => 1 )

Comment: what are you getting from  `$cat->getCategories();`

Comment: I get this: Array ( [1] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) )  which is not what i expect

Answer (score 1):

`$cat->getCategories()` returns an array, you add an array to another array each iteration, so is the result.

If you want to merge all the categories to a array, use `array_merge` instead:

```
$active_cat = array();
foreach ($act_prod as $act) {
    $cat = $this->getDi()->productTable->load($act);
    $active_cat = array_merge($active_cat, $cat->getCategories()); 
}
```

*And side note, it's quite not efficient do such loop, you may get all the categories with just one query.*

Comment: Are you sure about that one? Why is $active_cat being defined as something that contains $active_cat as well?